# 2D list of coordinates

Tags: python, list-comprehension, coordinates

I'm trying to create this function with this output

```
coords(3)

res = [[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)],
       [ (0, -1),  (0, 0),  (0, 1)],
       [ (1, -1),  (1, 0),  (1, 1)]]

coords(2)

res = [[(-1, -1), (0, -1)],
       [ (0, -1), (0, 0) ]]
```

Here's what I tried where I check if its odd or even, make a calculation with list comprehension but I'm having trouble creating coordinates.

```
def coords(N):

    # Create list with x, y
    lst = [int(N / -2 + i) if N % 2 == 0 else int((((N - 1) / -2) + i)) for i in range(0, N)]
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your examples are right..?

Comment: Yes, N increases with negative index first followed by a positive index. The grid is always 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly convinced the 2x2 example is correct. If I'm correct in that assumption, this does the trick:

```
def coords(n):
    xo = yo = -(n // 2)
    return [[(y + yo, x + xo) for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]


def print_grid(grid):
    print("[")
    for row in grid:
        print(" ", row)
    print("]")


print_grid(coords(2))
print_grid(coords(3))
```

The output (discrepancies pointed out):

```
[
  [(-1, -1), (-1, 0)]  # <- 2nd pair transposed
  [(0, -1), (0, 0)]
]
[
  [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)]
  [(0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
  [(1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a special coordinate system so this solution doesn't work for higher numbers, it's supposed to first increase by negative index, then positive index. See https://gyazo.com/f42339ce94c819332778d56a7fabce31

Comment: @Erik You... could have included that information in your original post, you know? :-)

Comment: @Erik How about now, with `xo`/`yo` computed according to that diagram?

Comment: Can you explain what xo and yo is? And why you take y + yo, x + xo?

Comment: xo/yo is "x offset", "y offset". They're (in this case) always negative, so they shift the coordinates to start from a negative value.